# how I attribute unit test with data driven and expected exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, attributes

I have a unit test function, which attribute as 'datadriven'.
it calls another function that expected to throw an exception.
if i attribute the both first method or the twice with "ExpectedException" it fails, and doesn't continue with the other rows on the data source.
what should I do?

Comment: Just add a catch inside the test and `Assert.Fail`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Assert.Throws()`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.6.1) method in NUnit to verify that a method within your test throws an exception.

```
Assert.Throws<FileNotFoundException>(() => ThisMethodThrowsFileNotFound());
```

The `ExpectedException` attribute is meant to be used on the test method (the one with the `Test` attribute). Decorating any other method with it has no effect.